# Is it okay to store session id in localStorage?

Tags: html, security, local-storage

Is it secure to store user's session id in [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)?   On [w3.org site](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute), they say

> User agents must raise a SECURITY_ERR exception whenever any of the
>   members of a Storage object originally returned by the localStorage
>   attribute are accessed by scripts whose effective script origin is not
>   the same as the origin of the Document of the Window object on which
>   the localStorage attribute was accessed.

So does this mean localStorage could be used for sensitive data?

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by sensitive. It will be stored in plain text and be accessible through the browser debugging features.

Comment: Which is no different than with a cookie

Comment: Are you sure you want to store it in `localStorage` and not `sessionStorage`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends upon what you mean by "is it secure"?

`localStorage` is about as secure as a non-path restricted cookie. From web pages, it can only be accessed by pages from the same domain. Zillions of sites store session ids in cookies which have about the same security restrictions as `localStorage`.

Outside of web pages, neither `localStorage` nor cookies are secure at all from access by other programs or even web debugging tools running on the same computer.

Answer (score 31):

`httpOnly` cookies provide a layer of XSS defence that `localStorage` does not provide:

- `httpOnly` cookies are not accessible from [potentially malicious] JS.
- `localStorage` *is* accessible from JS.

Session IDs should be stored in `httpOnly` `secure` cookies.

Comment: Cookies, however, are vulnerable to CSRF attacks and should therefore be secured with a CSRF prevention method (e.g. sending an additional non-`httpOnly` CSRF cookie to the client and returning its value in an HTTP header to the back-end, where it is first verified)